# Is there something wrong with my Python code? (functions)

Tags: python, django, queue, rabbitmq, celery

```
#tasks.py
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    add.delay(1, 9)
    return x + y

>>> import tasks
>>> res = tasks.add.delay(5, 2)
>>> res.result()
7
```

If I run this code, I expect tasks to be continously added to the queue.  But it's not! Only the first task (5,2) gets added to the queue and processed.

**There should continuously be tasks being added, due to this line: "add.delay(1,9)"**

Note: I need each task to execute another task.

Comment: First, you need the task to execute the same task, or another task?

Comment: Second, why do you need that? Is there a reason, or you are just attached to the current way of things?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, a periodic_task decorator is creating preiodic tasks, task creates just one task. And delay just executes it asynchronically.

You should just use periodic_task, instead of recursion.

Comment: No, I need each task to execute another task.  How would I do that?

Comment: What does that even mean? Can you describe for us exactly what you think `add.delay(1,9)` should do and why?

Comment: I think add.delay(1,9) would call the same function "add". Then, because there's a decorator, it would treat it as a task, in which case another task would run.  Tasks would continue to be created, and never ending.

Comment: Your async tasks may well run, as they run asynchronously, but you never use their output.

Comment: The fact is that it's not showing up in console. So I believe they are never run.

Comment: Well, your number 7 is shown due to the line res.result(), which returns the result of the task to the console. But inside tasks have no way to notify console of their result.

Comment: Try adding debug print (like print "task") to your def add(x, y) task, to check whether they are run.

Comment: @Kaerber, @TIMEX: print output from delayed taks will show only in the celeryd console (manage.py celeryd -l info), not in the python console.

Answer (score 0):

`add` inside function body refers to original function, not its decorated version.

If you just need to run task repeatedly, use `@periodic_task` instead.  You only need recursion if delay is different each time.  In this case, subclass `Task` instead of using decorator and you'll be able to use recursion without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at subtasks and callbacks, might give you the answer you are looking for

http://celeryproject.org/docs/userguide/tasksets.html